# Pick a random element from list/array of strings in netLogo

Tags: arrays, string, list, random, netlogo

I am new programmer in netlogo. I waned to know how can I pick a random string from a list/array of strings in netLogo? If anyone can please guide me, I will be very much thankful. Thanks

PS : I have done efforts on my part, I only know how to pick a random number from a number range like this

```
random-float (PRICE * 0.20) ;For float value (price is an integer defined by me)
random round (DifferenceAmt * 0.10) ; For random rounded amount
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use [`one-of`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#one-of), e.g.:

```
print one-of [ "a" "b" "c" ]
```

will print either `"a"`, `"b"` or `"c"`, at random.

Comment: I noticed that you were asking for both lists and arrays. Note that `one-of` doesn't work with arrays from the [`array` extension](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/arraystables.html), but those can be converted to a list with [`array:to-list`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/arraystables.html#array:to-list), so you can do: `one-of array:to-list my-array`. If speed is crucial, you could also do `array:item my-array one-of n-values array:length my-array [ ? ]`. But unless you have a very specific need for an array, you probably should not be using one.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help sir. This will do just fine for now :)

Comment: My pleasure. And by the way, the "fast" array version should have been: `array:item my-array random array:length`. (I don't think I was quite awake when I suggested using `n-values` for that...)