# How to add a random variable between a to z to a turtles-own

Tags: variables, random, netlogo

Is it possible to assign a random letter between a and z to a turtles-own? I know how to assign a random number but not a random letter.
My goal is to have each letter represent a breed and when two breeds produce offspring then the child will have letters from both parents.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pick a random element from list/array of strings in netLogo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38626112/pick-a-random-element-from-list-array-of-strings-in-netlogo)

Answer (score 1):

`item (random 26) "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"` will report a random lowercase letter